# Smartest way to draw symmetric QGraphicsRectItems

Tags: performance, qt, draw

I am writing a GUI that is supposed to display entities of a system in a 2D coordinate system, which the user can select and drag around. The system is mirror-symmetric w.r.t. the x and y axes. Currently I am subclassing an entity using a QGraphicsRectItem so that I can drag it around in the first quadrant (x>0, y>0) of the coordinate system. I reimplemented the paint method to draw the other three additional rectangles with painter.drawRectangle(). So when I move the entity in quadrant 1, the elements in the other three quadrants perform mirror motions. That works well.

[image: An entity and its symmetry partner in the other three quadrants. The entity can be subdivided, and that needs to be extended to the other three partners.]

In the next stage, each entity can be subdivided, i.e. consist of hundreds of rectangles. So I need to draw hundreds of rectangles and that four times, with mirror operations. The naive approach takes four for-loops, but I'm wondering if there is a smarter way of doing this in QT. The for-loops hurt a little because I'm using PyQt.

Comment: Probably should look into redrawing this rather than duplicating items. I can't write a proper answer now but... I think you can subclass QGraphicsScene and its draw event, scale the QPainter by -1 and call the base implementation again

Comment: Yes, I think that should be possible, but that would still require all the for-loops. Maybe I should have phrased my question better. I was thinking along the lines of a blit operation or something remotely like a display list like in OpenGL, somehting fast and internal to Qt.

Comment: What about generating a single image (one loop) and rendering it four (or more) times? For example generate a `QImage`, create multiple `QGraphicsPixmapItem`s with the same image and place them on your scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your drawing operations are so slow the simplest thing you could do is draw to an image, and then simply draw the cached painting from the image 4 times, which will be very fast, since it will just be copying some pixel values.

It might be efficient to cache the drawing result not on item basis but to cache a quadrant of your grid. This way if you zoom in and the items get huge or numerous in count, you won't be wasting lots of memory, instead you will only need one image cache that's the screen size of the quadrant.

It really depends what you want to achieve, which at this point is not entirely clear from the description, and your image isn't showing neither.

Comment: I wonder why my image isn't showing. Sorry for that. I see it on my rendering of the page.